# Filling in column by group

Tags: r

I would like to fill in a column by group.

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  base = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA))
```

So the desired outcome would be:

```
1     1    2
2     1    2
3     1    2
4     2    3
5     2    3
6     2    3
```

This is my code so far, but this doesn't seem to work:

`base <- group_by(group) %>% summarize(base = max(base))`

Any other alternatives?

Comment: try `df %>% group_by(group) %>% fill(base, .direction = 'updown')`

Comment: Thank you. That worked.